# Is it possible to change this code in order to avoid the use of the C++ lambda expression?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have this code and I would like to know if I can change it in order to avoid the use of the lambda expression:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class B
{
public:
    B( double b ):b_(b){}
    double b_;
};

class A
{
public:
    double error( const B& b ) const {return a_-b.b_;};
    double a_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector< B > bs;
    std::vector< double > ds;

    A a;
    a.a_ = 10;
    bs.push_back( B(1) );
    bs.push_back( B(2) );
    bs.push_back( B(3) );
    std::transform( bs.begin(), bs.end(), 
                    std::back_inserter( ds ), 
                    [&a](const B& b){return a.error(b);} );

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to keep the `std::transform` but without the lambda.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Boost::bind ?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @DeadMG I have no valid reason to do such a thing. I just would like to learn about some "functional" language features I am not so familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, an equivalent functor is:

```
struct CallError {
    A &a;
    CallError(A &a) : a(a) {}
    double operator()(const B &b) { return a.error(b); }
};
```

Then:

```
std::transform( bs.begin(), bs.end(), 
                std::back_inserter( ds ),
                CallError(a));
```

Note that anything captured by the lambda needs a corresponding data member of the functor. "Capture everything" lambdas are therefore a little trickier, since you need to work out which variables the lambda actually uses. The other thing that the lambda does for you, in this case where the lambda body consists of a single return statement, is that it automatically works out the return type.

Comment: Thank you. I think -> should be .

Comment: Fixed. ffssoletmepostmycomment

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Just do it like we've been doing in C++03 for years: with a function object.

Most (if not all) references for `std::transform` (and similar algorithms) will have examples of this.

Answer (score 2):

Might contain syntax or typo errors

```
double fn(const A &a, const B &b) {
   return a.error(b);
}

....

using std::placeholders::_1;

std::transform( bs.begin(), bs.end(), 
                std::back_inserter( ds ), 
                boost::bind(fn, a, _1) );
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do the same with std::bind1st ?

Answer (score 1):

Just spelling out Tomalak's answer:

```
struct ErrorFunctor {
  double a;
  ErrorFunctor(double a) : a(a) { }
  inline double operator()(const B & b) const { return a - b.b_; }
};

// ... later on ...
std::transform(bs.begin(), bs.end(), std::back_inserter(ds), ErrorFunctor(10));
```

The function object's work has to be accessed via the `operator()`.

Comment: Yes, and don't confuse `operator()` for the constructor invokation.