# How to modify elements in lists of different types?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

how can I efficiently modify the elements of these two lists using stl algorithms:

```
std::list<std::pair<double, string> > listPair(10);
std::list<double> listA(10);
```

And in such a way that the first pair-element gets the corresponding double value from listA?

Comment: Why do you make two lists? More efficiently use a std::map.
Else, I see no other choice but taking two iterators and making a simple for loop

Comment: I have to use two lists. Actually, this is a (very) broken down example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I assume `listPair` is already filled, because there's no way to get that string otherwise.

---

You could loop through the collections directly.

```
auto a_cur = listA.begin(), a_end = listA.end();
auto pair_cur = listPair.begin();
for (; a_cur != a_end; ++ a_cur, ++ pair_cur) {
    pair_cur->first = *a_cur;
}
```

or use the "binary" version of `std::transform`, but this will involve copying the string:

```
std::transform(listA.begin(), listA.end(), listPair.begin(), listPair.begin(),
               [](double a, std::pair<double, string> b) {
                   return std::make_pair(a, b.second);
               });
```

Comment: I wanted to use the code from the first block; but I thought about using stl algorithms because it reduces the amount of code that I hack, and it makes it easier to read for other people. Whenever I try to use stl algorithms, it seems that they (and the function objects they envoke) really rely a lot on copying the data, which in my case, makes the code not so efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Try using C++11 lambdas

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::pair<double, std::string> > listPair(10);
    std::list<double> listA(10);

    // original question: assign double of listA to listPair
    std::transform(
        listA.begin(), listA.end(), listPair.begin(), listPair.begin(), 
        [](double d, std::pair<double, std::string> const& p) {
            return std::make_pair(d, p.second);
        }
    ); 

    // other way around: assign double from listPair to listA
    std::transform(
        listPair.begin(), listPair.end(), back_inserter(listA), 
        [](std::pair<double, std::string> const& p) {
            return p.first;
        }
    );

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I think the question is asking doing it other way.. i.e. fill `listPair` using `listA`, also shouldn't you iterator adaptor such as `inserter` as the destination list will be empty.

Comment: Oops.. I am wrong about the second part of my comment. `10` default objects are already constructed in `listA`.

Comment: I'm working on a huge library that doesn't use C++11 yet. Thanks + thumbs up anyway. :)

Comment: @tomislav-maric There is also Boost.Lambda, if you can use that.

Comment: @tomislav-maric: Just define a function/struct instance, and then refer to that. A lambda is simply a syntactic sugar of it. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408881/is-it-possible-to-change-this-code-in-order-to-avoid-the-use-of-the-c-lambda-e.